# ORA-0090: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

```
    create table vote
           (
          vote_id number(7) NOT NULL,
           artwork_id int(20),
            person_id int(20),
          PRIMARY KEY (vote_id)
          );

ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Can't find out what I am miising I know it is small mistake.

Comment: What is `NUMBER(7)`? Always [check the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html) when you get errors like this. This is also an ORA- prefixed error so this probably isn't even MySQL you're talking about.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Another thing to note is to get out of the habit of specifying things like `INT(20)` and instead go with defaults. `INT` can't handle 20 places by default, only `BIGINT` can, but you're not using that.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use number for artwork_id and person_id as well?

```
   create table vote
       (
      vote_id number(7) NOT NULL,
       artwork_id number(20),
        person_id number(20),
      PRIMARY KEY (vote_id)
      );
```

Or if you insist on having an integer type:

```
create table vote
       (
      vote_id number(7) NOT NULL,
       artwork_id int,
        person_id int,
      PRIMARY KEY (vote_id)
      );
```

You cannot assign a limit to the number of integers for an integer type since it assumes that it will accept up to the maximum integer limit (2147483647)

Comment: `create table vote
       (
      vote_id number(7) NOT NULL,
       artwork_id number(20),
       person_id number(20),
      PRIMARY KEY (vote_id),
      FOREIGN KEY (artwork_id),
      FORIGN KEY ( person_id)
) ;`  ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword  .I am getting this  new error now,\.

Comment: you need to add the CONSTRAINT keyword to create a key, then for foreign keys, you need to add the REFERENCE keyword and supply the table and field on which the foreign key will refer to. https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php